# Declare a Structure and a Function Reference that use Each Other

Tags: c, function, reference, struct, declare

I need to declare a (typedef'd) structure and a (typedef'd) function reference in pain old C.  This is my code:

```
typedef void (*monitor_calback)(monitor_data*, short int, short int, void*);

typedef struct
{
    int port;
    unsigned char port_state;

    monitor_calback cb_high[8];
    void *cb_high_data[8];
    monitor_calback cb_low[8];
    void *cb_low_data[8];
} monitor_data;
```

But of course it doen't compile because we don't know about the structure when the function reference is declared.

I have gotten this but it looks kinda messy and is a little hard to read.

```
struct _monitor_data;

typedef void (*monitor_calback)(struct _monitor_data*, short int, short int, void*);

typedef struct _monitor_data
{
    int port;
    unsigned char port_state;

    monitor_calback cb_high[8];
    void *cb_high_data[8];
    monitor_calback cb_low[8];
    void *cb_low_data[8];
} monitor_data;
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Doesn't look messy to me. The difference is really minimal.

Comment: You should add `struct _monitor_data;` line before `monitor_calback` definition (in the second code fragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typedef a struct before defining it:

```
typedef struct _monitor_data monitor_data;

typedef void (*monitor_calback)(monitor_data*, short int, short int, void*);

struct _monitor_data
{
    int port;
    unsigned char port_state;

    monitor_calback cb_high[8];
    void *cb_high_data[8];
    monitor_calback cb_low[8];
    void *cb_low_data[8];
};
```

This will work fine as long as you don't try to reference the internal structure of `monitor_data` before `struct _monitor_data` is fully defined. All the compiler needs to know for your `monitor_callback` definition is that `monitor_data *` is a pointer to something so `monitor_callback` is fine as long as the compiler knows that `monitor_data` exists.

This sort of construct is the standard approach for defining opaque types in C, you'd just be un-opaquing your type rather than leaving it opaque.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefer the following, depends on taste tho:

```
    #define monitor_data struct _monitor_data
    typedef void (*monitor_calback)(monitor_data*, short int, short int, void*);

    typedef struct _monitor_data
    {
        int port;
        unsigned char port_state;

        monitor_calback cb_high[8];
        void *cb_high_data[8];
        monitor_calback cb_low[8];
        void *cb_low_data[8];
    };
```

Comment: In my opinion this doesn't make the code clearer. So `struct _monitor_data` is the best choice.

Comment: And of course you still have to declare `struct _monitor_calback` before its use in `monitor_calback` definition.

Comment: nope, that's the point; its not needed. I use gcc's linker and original poster seems to have a linker that does it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way because of `typedef` behavior.